# Is there a way to improve a for-loop implementation in Scala from Java

Tags: java, scala, loops, enums

I have written a method in Java that I want to rewrite to Scala. (Sales.Metrics is an `Enum`)

```
for (int i = 0; i < Sales.Metrics.values().length; i++) {
    Sales.Metrics value = Sales.Metrics.values()[i];
    if (!metricValue.isSet(value)) {
        metricValue.setMetric(value, true);
    }
}
```

So I came up with the following implementation but I suspect that it may not optimal. Maybe I'm missing some cool Scala features. Is it the right way to go with a for-loop in Scala?

```
for (i <- Sales.Metrics.values().length) {
  val value: Sales.Metrics = Sales.Metrics.values()(i)
  if (!metricValue.isSet(value)) metricValue.setMetric(value, true)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generator `i <- arr.length` in you code does not seem to make any sense. Looks as if it should have been something like

```
for (value <- Sales.Metrics.values() if !metricValue.isSet(value)) {
  metricValue.setMetric(value, true)
}
```

Remarks:

1. In the body of the foreach-loop, you never use the *index* of the value for anything, you use only `value`. Therefore, you don't have to iterate through the indices, you can directly iterate through the values.
2. Scala's allows [guards](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#for-comprehensions-and-for-loops) inside the `for`-expressions / `for`-loops, so you can combine Java's `for` and `if` into one control structure.

---

Also note that your original Java code could also be rewritten without explicit indices:

```
for (TypeOfValues v: Sales.Metrics.values()) {
    if (!metricValue.isSet(v)) {
        metricValue.setMetric(v, true);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you could probably avoid using Semi Colon ";"  to cope with Scala style here, as it is mainly used in Java context. :)

Comment: @madhawaOnline Couldn't really test the code, because the OP gave no definition of what `Sales.Metrics` is supposed to be, wasn't quite sure whether the semicolon can be omitted here without line break and curly braces... But yeah, you are probably right, the semicolon is superfluous here, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sales.Metrics.values() foreach { value =>
   if (!metricValue.isSet(value)) metricValue.setMetric(value, true)
}
```

I'd use the *foreach* here, because what you need is just a side effect.

Depending on the implementation of `Metrics` class you may need `asScala`-converter (see `import collection.JavaConverters._`).

Comment: From `Sales.Metrics.values()[i]`, you can infer that it must be an array - there are no other data structures in Java that accept indexing with square brackets. Actually, there is nothing else in Java that accepts square brackets...

Answer (score 1):

As you have asked for Scala language features, you could consider using scala advance features like "for comprehension" for iterating through lists based on your requirement. Normally we are using the Scala For Comprehension with Yield to yield new list with expected result.
The conditional guard is also applied same as in for each.

```
for {
  value <- Sales.Metrics.values()
  if !metricValue.isSet(value)
} yield metricValue.setMetric(value, true)
```